Boot Black screen With ro quiet splash
When I turn on my laptop, I encounter the GRUB Boot screen where I can choose between different Linux options such as Ubuntu and Kali. However, when I attempt to boot normally, I encounter a freeze on a black screen, or if there's any message from the Linux system, it freezes after displaying the message. I often have to reboot 3 to 5 times until it works correctly. I've tried various solutions such as updating the BIOS and updating the graphics card, but without success.
I found a solution to remove "ro quiet splash" and add "nomodeset," but the system then opens with a large-scale screen and poor graphics. These issues have occurred in Kali, Ubuntu, and all other Linux distributions.
